# How do I install a specific video codec in Ubuntu?

Tags: video, codecs, medibuntu

Before you ask, yes, I've installed Medibuntu. This codec is not in that pack--specifically I am trying to install SCLS.dll, which stands for Screen Capture Lossless Codec, a codec that works with CamStudio's desktop recording software.

It works fine in Windows, but when I have attempted to install it on Linux, I have had zero luck through Ubuntu itself, or through Wine. When I install through Wine, GOM player simply crashes and Windows Media Player won't load the files at all--those are the only two media players I know of that have correctly made use of the SCLS codec in Windows--and in Ubuntu, the "Videos" program can't find it--so I suppose the second part of my question would be how to direct the "Videos" program to my codec?

Answer (score 1):

> a codec that works with CamStudio's desktop recording software.

Sadly, if the makers don't make available the codec for the community in binary (or even better the source) is unlikely that you can use the codec in any Linux distributions.

> This codec is free for non-commercial use.
>
> To use it in commercial projects buy a license here.

[Here](http://www.compression.ru/video/ls-codec/screen_capture_codec_en.html) free means as no-cost per use.

Seems also [that mplayer might support](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/codecs-status.html) this codec. Is unclear if they mean that the can reproduce the codec or that they are able to codec raw video into this codec.

### For people that are interested in adding codecs

Normally an `apt-cache search <name of the codec>` should suffice. In this particular case it returned non-useful results:

```
apt-cache search scls
texlive-latex-base - TeX Live: Basic LaTeX packages
```

Other codecs might have more luck.

Comment: Hmm...I've tried mPlayer--but that also gave me non-functional results. Perhaps point me in the direction of a tutorial to test to see if it's really working or not? I'm so new to Ubuntu, it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that both 64bit and 32bit versions of MPlayer will now play these files, certainly the one that I have downloaded from [the MPlayer sample site](http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/tscc/TI_1_Einfuehrung.avi). A recent enough MPlayer will use *ffcamtasia*, which I demonstrate on this snipped piece of the MPlayer output:

```
==========================================================================
Trying to force video codec driver family ffmpeg...
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 55.60.103 (internal)
Selected video codec: [ffcamtasia] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec)
==========================================================================
```

And so 32bit users should have a choice of either the windows codec (dll) *or* the native implementation:

```
andrew@skamandros~$ mplayer -vc help | grep -i camtasia

ffcamtasia  ffmpeg    working   FFmpeg TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec  [camtasia]
fftscc2     ffmpeg    working   FFmpeg TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec 2  [tscc2]
camtasia    vfw       working   TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec  [tsccvid.dll]
camtasia2   vfw       working   TechSmith Camtasia Screen Codec 2  [tsc2_codec32.dll]
```

If you dislike the command-line, as some do, SMPlayer should also play these files...